# Drawing a shape fixing two coordinates IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I wanted to draw an arrow in the following way:

```
- (void) drawArrowWithContext:(CGContextRef)context atPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint withSize: (CGSize)size lineWidth:(float)width arrowHeight:(float)aheight andColor:(UIColor *)color
{
float width_wing = (size.width-width)/2;
float main = size.height-aheight;

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[color CGColor]);

CGPoint rectangle_points[] =
{
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + width_wing, startPoint.y + 0.0),
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + width_wing, startPoint.y + main),
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + 0.0, startPoint.y + main), // left point
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width/2, startPoint.y + size.height),

    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width, startPoint.y + main), // right point

    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width-width_wing, startPoint.y + main),

    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + size.width-width_wing, startPoint.y + 0.0),
    CGPointMake(startPoint.x + width_wing, startPoint.y + 0.0),
};

CGContextAddLines(context, rectangle_points, 8);

CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

As you can see I can fix the starting coordinate (CGPoint)startPoint but I also wanted to fix the final point. Until now the arrow always points downwards. By fixing the final point I should be able to point it in any direction as well as getting rid of the size. How can I insert this in my method??